# Angular directive replace dom node with template with nested directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a really strange use case.

I want to take an element, place a structural directive on it, then replace that element with a template (chosen at run time) that has that nested structural directive on a child node with an ng-repeat.

example:

```
<div item-structure item="root"></div>
```

This is the directive I've written:

```
function itemStructure($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      item: "=",
    },  
    priority: 900,
    controller: function() {
      var self = this;

      self.deleteNode = function(parent, node) {
        if(parent)
          parent.children.splice(parent.children.indexOf(node), 1);
        console.log(parent, node);
      }
      console.log(self.item.id + ' ' +self.item.type);
      console.log(self.item.children);
    },
    controllerAs: "vm",
    bindToController: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
      scope.$watch(watchNode, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue) {
          var type = newValue.type;
          console.log(scope.vm.item.children);
          var content = "<div class='item'> {{vm.item.id}} - {{vm.item.type}} <div ng-repeat='child in vm.item.children' item-structure item='child'> {{child.item.type}} </div> </div>";
          var newElement = angular.element(content);

          var overlayContent = "<div class='overlay' ng-click='vm.deleteNode($parent.vm.item, vm.item)'> </div>";
          var overlayElement = angular.element(overlayContent);
          newElement.prepend(overlayElement);

          element.replaceWith($compile(newElement)(scope));
        }
      }, true);

      function watchNode() {
        var original = angular.copy(scope.vm.item);
        if (original.children)
          original.childrenLength = original.children.length;
        delete original.children;
        return original;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Oddly enough, this works for many deep nested levels (though performance degrades), however, when I attempt to change a collection (add or remove items), the directive renders in the ng-repeat but does not get transformed.

For the time being, I hooked delete up to the green rectangle.

Another odd feature, adding an item will put it at the top of the collection, not at the bottom.

Perhaps I should be using transclude for this?  I tried with not much luck.

Plunkr, here: https://plnkr.co/edit/aYiz883Cx6O8XP05wABo?p=preview

Any help is greatly appreciated.